# css to force child div to the bottom of dynamically sized parent div

Tags: html, css

I tried searching existing solutions on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me.

I am using the visual composer plugin and I have created a parent div which contains a wallpaper picture. I have used the following css to make the picture stretch on all screen sizes.

```
.backgroundHome
{
    background: no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;


}
```

This css works perfect for me but now I have created a new inner line within the parent (aka child div) that I want to force to the bottom of the parent div. I only want to do that when the page loads but when you scroll the child div must scroll as well with the rest of the page. Please bear in mind that the parent's height is dynamically generated based on the screen size hence setting the parent and child to position absolute and fixed didn't work

Answer (score 1):

It would be usefull if you had an html snippet as an example, but I would try just using `position: absolute`? You said that the heigth of the parent is set dynamically but in order to scroll the content must be longer then the parent container. The code below will allways make the `.child` element stick to the bottom of your container.

```
.parent {
  position: relative
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I started wondering if the parent div is expanding dynamically. Would you agree that it does based on the css code:

Comment: .backgroundHome
{
    background: no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;


}